# Dropwizard auth users

Tags: java, authentication, dropwizard

I was doing some research about drop-wizard security and authentication. Here is the link that I used http://howtodoinjava.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-basic-auth-security-example/.

My question is how to actually create new users, since VALID_USERS is a static final and can't be changed. I was thinking about creating a database, and that would consist of user object that contains the username and role ex. admin. (I don't need a password) But I am confused what I would return. In their example they returned Optional.of(new User(credentials.getUsername(), VALID_USERS.get(credentials.getUsername())));
Would I return a user object?

Essentially, I want to authenticate a user by the username and give them a role of authorization ex. admin, basic. But I guess I am confused how to generate a list of users and their roles. I was thinking of making a database, but I am not sure how exactly I would implement that.

```
    public class AppBasicAuthenticator implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials, User> 
{
    private static final Map<String, Set<String>> VALID_USERS = ImmutableMap.of(
        "guest", ImmutableSet.of(),
        "user", ImmutableSet.of("USER"),
        "admin", ImmutableSet.of("ADMIN", "USER")
    );

    @Override
    public Optional<User> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException 
    {
        if (VALID_USERS.containsKey(credentials.getUsername()) && "password".equals(credentials.getPassword())) 
        {
            return Optional.of(new User(credentials.getUsername(), VALID_USERS.get(credentials.getUsername())));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the latest version of DropWizard you can find it possible both to do Authentication and Authorization. The former, in a nutshell, instructs DropWizard to ask a user for credentials if you use basic authentication when she tries to access a resource or provide some other  identity check. The latter allows one to grant a user access to various resources based on user's roles.

The are various possibilities how you can store user data and roles. Examples include a database which you mentioned, a LDAP server and a third-party identity management system.

If you are interested in Basic Authentication, you can take a look at my example [here](https://github.com/javaeeeee/DropBookmarks). A database is used to store user's credentials. Also, here is my little bit dated tutorial on [DropWizard authentication](http://javaeeeee.blogspot.ca/2015/02/getting-started-with-dropwizard.html). The code for the latest version is in the aforementioned example application.

To implement authentication only, you can skip adding roles and registering an Authorizer. To add authorization you can add a roles collection to your User entity and use annotations such as @RolesAllowed and @PermitAll along with Authorizer implementation to grant/deny access to your resources.

A link to DropWizard authentication docs is [here](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.3/docs/manual/auth.html).

Please feel free to ask more questions in comments and good luck.

Comment: Hey Thanks alot! I found your example to be really useful. One question I had was how to create two levels of users, Admin and a guest, that would have different permissions. Could you give me some tips on how to do that?

Comment: The idea is that you can use a collection of strings in your user objects; strings are actually roles. JPA/Hibernate allows you do that (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-value). After that you should implement an Authorizer, an example from Dropwizard project is below, and register in the run() method of the application class. After that, you can secure your methods using @RolesAllowed annotation, where you provide a comma-separated list of roles like @RolesAllowed("ADMIN").

Comment: public class ExampleAuthorizer implements Authorizer<User> {

    @Override
    public boolean authorize(User user, String role) {
        return user.getRoles() != null && user.getRoles().contains(role);
    }
} This is an autorizer from DropWizard example application.